# Win32 App not running in window but in console

Tags: c++, winapi, console

I've created a windows application in c++ through platinum.
When i run this app, it'll run in command prompt
Now, i want to run it from windows so i managed it to run in windows
But, the problem is that i can't run the app in command prompt and windows concurrently.
It only allows me to run either in windows or in command prompt (not both)
Can anybody lead me to the correct path.

Comment: Very hard to know what you are asking, but I suspect you wish to have an application that can be either console or GUI depending on how it starts. Well, that's not possible. The information is coded in the PE metadata. The standard solution is two executables. Examples include java.exe/javaw.exe, python.exe/pythonw.exe

Answer (score 0):

If you need both a console and a window you can start the app as a console one and then create a window with the [Windows API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384843.aspx).

Example here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

long __stdcall WindowProcedure( HWND window, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp )
{
  switch(msg)
  {
  case WM_DESTROY:
    std::cout << "\ndestroying window\n" ;
    PostQuitMessage(0) ;
    return 0L ;
  case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    std::cout << "\nmouse left button down at (" << LOWORD(lp)
      << ',' << HIWORD(lp) << ")\n" ;
    // fall thru
  default:
    std::cout << '.' ;
    return DefWindowProc( window, msg, wp, lp ) ;
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::cout << "hello world!\n" ;
  const char* const myclass = "myclass" ;
  WNDCLASSEX wndclass = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX), CS_DBLCLKS, (WNDPROC)WindowProcedure,
    0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION),
    LoadCursor(0,IDC_ARROW), HBRUSH(COLOR_WINDOW+1),
    0, (LPCWSTR)myclass, LoadIcon(0,IDI_APPLICATION) } ;
  if( RegisterClassEx(&wndclass) )
  {
    HWND window = CreateWindowEx( 0, (LPCWSTR)myclass, (LPCWSTR)"title",
      WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, GetModuleHandle(0), 0 ) ;
    if(window)
    {
      ShowWindow( window, SW_SHOWDEFAULT ) ;
      MSG msg ;
      while( GetMessage( &msg, 0, 0, 0 ) ) DispatchMessage(&msg) ;
    }
  }
}
```

Taken from [this link](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/608057-how-do-you-create-a-win32-window-from-console-application/#entry4846215) (and taken from somewhere else)

Comment: Thanks for quick input.
I've tried it and worked as expected.
But i don't think i can design through this API.
Do you know anything else regarding this?